# Replacing text delete rest of text in textbox

Tags: string, replace, textbox, vb6

I am using following code to replace text

```
Text1.Text = Replace(quer, "demoo", "demo")
```

i am using multiline textbox
which is filled up with 10lines of text

i just want to find and replace word "demoo" with "demo" on line 1 only

even if line2 or another lines contain "demoo", i just want to replace on line1

Comment: VB.NET or VB6? These are completely different languages.

Comment: @KonradRudolph sorry, i need for vb6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim lines() As String

    If Len(Text1.Text) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    lines = Split(Text1.Text, vbCrLf)
    lines(0) = Replace(lines(0), "demoo", "demo")
    Text1.Text = Join(lines, vbCrLf)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the **[TextBoxBase.Lines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx)** property.

```
Dim lines As String() = Me.TextBox1.Lines
lines(0) = lines(0).Replace("demoo", "demo")
Me.TextBox1.Lines = lines
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake. i need for vb6